# rewrite url and get variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I get the second part of a url to be a variable, rewrite it, and provide a fancy URL.

So example `www.mywebsite.com/AFL` would rewrite to `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?league=AFL` but would still display as `www.mywebsite.com/AFL`.

I am using the same pages for multiple leagues. When a user signs up they establish a league name in the database and then on each page I look for the league variable to display the info.

I also have many different pages.  So a user could go to `www.mywebsite/AFL/schedule_teamdisplay.php?Team=ABC&Year=2014`.  This would rewrite to `www.mywebsite.com/schedule_teamdisplay.php?league=ALF&Team=ABC&Year=2014`.

The league will always be the second entry in the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in your root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?league=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$2?league=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That worked perfect, exactly what I wanted. I was trying to do it with php and database as a mapping, and this was so easy.  I have to spend some more time with the htaccess it seems very powerful.